# bot in discord js automatically skips track after using /play

Tags: windows, ubuntu, discord.js

My bot, after using the /play command, skips the song and shows a message that the queue is over, but this problem occurs only on VPS from OVH on ubuntu and on my windows computer everything works normally (does not send any error)

modules used:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "cli-color": "^2.0.3",
    "discord-html-transcripts": "^3.1.4",
    "discord.js": "^14.10.2",
    "fivem": "^2.1.8",
    "distube": "^4.0.4",
    "@distube/spotify": "^1.5.1",
    "ffmpeg-static": "^4.4.1",
    "tweetnacl": "^1.0.3"
  }
```

reinstalling modules, removing bot, restarting vps